# Building binary python distributions for multiple OS X versions

Tags: python, macos, build, cross-compiling, distutils

I am attempting to build a python application with binary modules on OS X.  I want to build versions for Snow Leopard and Leopard from Lion.  I have XCode 4 installed with the 10.5 and 10.6 sdks and have been attempting to build using the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET flag set to 10.6.  I receive an error from distutils complaining that python was built with a different deployment target.

I tried building a separate python binary with the deployment target set to 10.6 and then used virtualenv to try to build from that, but virtualenv expected a lib directory under the base env directory that was not there.

I am a total newb at developing on Mac and not even sure if what I want to do is possible.  Am I going to have to break down and have someone still running Snow Leopard build my distributions?

I really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What are you using to build your binary packages? My guess is that as long as your python interp is built with i386 and x86_64, and you maybe set MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5, the binaries should still work across them all?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  If I enter "MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6 python setup.py build"  I get the error distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: $MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET mismatch: now "10.6" but "10.7" during configure.

Comment: I am assuming that during configure refers the the original configuration of the python install.

Comment: You may need to build another python from source instead of using the 2.7 interp that comes with Lion. You can build it FAT with i386 and x86_64 and use MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5. this is kind of where virtualdev might help you out, since you can switch to it, build a python and just use it for your build environment instead of messing with your main python 2.7 interp

Comment: Ya, 10.7 refers to when python was build, which shipped with Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system Pythons shipped by Apple in OS X 10.7 are built for 10.7 only.  The simplest solution is to download the most recent [Python 2.7 or 3.2 64-bit/32-bit installer from python.org](http://www.python.org/download/) and use it since it is a universal binary that will run on either 10.6 or 10.7.  If you are making an app bundle, you'll need to install a copy of `py2app` for it and any other 3rd-party packages like `Distribute` (aka `easy_install`) or `pip`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, go into your /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/distutils/sysconfig.py

Goto line 408 that says "raise DistutilsPlatformError" and add a '#' to comment out that line of code... This will "unleash the python"

You are basically telling python "don't worry its not 10.7, I know" there could be some crashes as a result but I think otherwise. My very complex python applicaiton now compiles on MacOSX 10.8 with no troubles and it seems to do the job, QA still has to test it though.

Comment: Hacking system Python sources is really not something to be recommended.

Comment: You are correct, if there was any other solution I would go for it first